Sequence of random variables : $X_{n+1} = X_{n} + \ln(X_{n}) Y_n$ where $Y_n\sim \text{Exp}(1)$ : any findings?
In regards to prime numbers, there is this conjecture that the merit of primes $\frac{p_{n+1} - p_{n}}{\ln(p_{n})}$ converges (in a relevant sense) towards an exponential law of parameter 1. Starting from this, I am interested in the sequence of random variables defined as $X_{n+1} = X_{n} + \ln(X_{n})Y_n$ where $Y_n$ are i.i.d. $\text{Exp}(1)$ and $X_{1} = 2$.
What is the asymptotic behaviour of that sequence of random variables? In terms of 'mean', 'variance', 'further moments', 'distribution function'? Any help greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My hunch is that $X_n\sim n\ln n$ (taking the expectation and comparing with the differential equation)
